# SCD TYPE2 in ssis using start and end date

Tags: ssis

I want load data from stagging to model from source table to dimension in the model,I want to apply the following:

### source table:

### ID|Name     |STRDATE|ENDDATE

1,amr hassan,1-1-2016,2099-12-31

after applying update on the name column from'amr hassan' to 'amr',I want the new updated record to look like the following in the target table:

### Dim_target_table:

### ID|Name     |STRDATE|ENDDATE

### 1,amr hassan,1-1-2016,21-1-2016

1,   amr    ,21-1-2016,2099-12-31

Answer (score 0):

after look up create one condition split  with in condition split
wirte this logic.

For new records purpose `:ISNULL(LKP_EMPNO)` and update  purpose `:(ENAME != LKP_ENAME || SAL != LKP_SAL) && (LKP_EMPNO == EMPNO)`
end of condition split connect one oldeb designation  it is loaded new  records  and other end  is connect to multicast  with multicast  connect to  oldeb designation  and  second one is    oledb command
 with command wirite this query

```
Update  EMPLOYEE_D set ename=?,sal=?,enddate=getdate(),currentflag=0 where  DW_EMP_ID=?
```

DW_EMP_ID is  identity column

Comment: Sorry Grir,I am not using lookup transformation,I am using (OLEDB source,slowly changing dimension transformation only) should i use lookup transfomration???

Answer (score -1):

No need to do anything.Just drag scd tranformation ..it will take care of it....
http://www.msbiguide.com/2012/03/how-to-defineimplement-type-2-scd-in-ssis-using-slowly-changing-dimension-transformation/

Happy?

Comment: Thank you for your rsponse,but let me clarify it ,I have the following value(2099-12-21) as a default value for the end date column and the start date column in the dimesnion is mapped to a source column called'eff_date',What i want to apply is I want the first record to have the start date from the column eff_Date and the end date have the value(2099-12-21),and the second record inserted(incase of any updates happened) to have in the start date column(today_date for example:21-1-2016) and the end date(default value:2099-12-21).

Comment: and the end date of the old record to be updated (today_date for example:21-1-2016)to be equal the start date of the new inserted record